# Understanding laravel 'auth' and 'web' middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have strange behavior on one of route groups I have defined e.g

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['web','auth']], function (){
  //admin routes
 }
);
```

Whenever I defined `'middleware' => ['web','auth'],` routes are accessible after login , but  without 'web' I am redirected to `/` home.

[What I thought was that](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/web-middleware-in-laravel-52) , 'web' is default middleware injected ,please correct me if I am wrong. Otherwise there is some other setting that is affecting this behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

Laravel comes with `web` middleware groups that contains common middleware you may want to apply to web UI routes. the `web` middleware group is automatically applied to your default `routes.php` file by the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: true, but not applied unless specified explicitly

Comment: Makwan check my answer

Answer (score 3):

The web [middleware](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/web-middleware-in-laravel-52) is default now, but if you have create laravel app skeleton a while ago you have to update the [route provider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) . You can see the changes in this [diff](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed)